# SOQL EventRelation is Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, code, test-setup

The issue with SOQL on EventRelation filtered by Relation.Type is working as expected during normal execution. However, while executing the following LOC in test class it causes failure.

Code:

```
List<EventRelation> evrList = [ SELECT EventId, Event.WhatId, Event.Subject, Event.What.Type, Relation.Type, RelationId 
FROM EventRelation  WHERE EventId = :eventIdSet AND Event.What.Type = 'Account' ];

for( EventRelation evr : evrList ) {
     System.debug( 'Event 1 > ' + evr.EventId + ' WhatId - ' + evr.Event.WhatId + ' RelationId - ' + evr.RelationId );
     Id relationId = evr.RelationId;
     System.debug( 'Relation Type > ' + relationId.getSobjectType() );
}

System.debug( 'Event 2 > ' + [ SELECT EventId, RelationId FROM EventRelation WHERE EventId = :eventIdSet 
        AND Event.What.Type = 'Account' AND Relation.Type = 'Contact' ] );
```

> While running these statements in the test class, the following debug log is generated:

```
Event 1 > 00U4p000009doMlEAI WhatId - 0014p00001gxIF8AAM RelationId- 0034p00001g3OLkAAM

Relation Type > Contact

Event 2 > ()
```

**From RelationId "0034p00001g3OLkAAM" it is clear that Relation.Type is Contact but while running Test class, filter criteria Relation.Type = 'Contact' does not not return any record.**

Comment: is testmethod at latest v48?

Comment: test class and main class both at API version 48